# JMeter hanging when handling large API responses, how to resolve?"

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am recording a jmeter script for online assessment project. But while recording my jmeter is getting hang because there is 1 API whose response is very large. Once this API comes in Jmeter then I am not able to do anything on the JMeter for some interval of time.

I am using the latest version of Jmeter i.e. 5.6.2

I have tried to increase the heap size memory, and also done the same thing on the AWS server still I was still getting the same error.

Please give the solution to record the script without getting lag whether the API response is large.
Are there any changes or steps to perform on the JMeter? please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can disable [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. If you're using Recording Template there are 2 of them
2. If it is not enough use a profiler tool like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to identify the component which is causing delay and see whether you can safely remove it.
3. Switch to an alternative recording option like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have tried to record the script after disabling the View Results Tree Listener. The original issue is that there is 1 API whose payload size is very large in body data i.e. Content-Length = 981613. So the JMeter tool is getting hung when this is API encountered. Please give me the solution for this as I am not able to proceed further because of this. Thanks